# UITextField in UITableView post 3.0 should automatically support scrolling above the keyboard?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, keyboard

I thought that adding a textfield or textview to a scrollview or table view automatically supported scrolling above the keyboard when needed.
Has support for this been lost?
I have a table view containing textviews that previously had this behavior but now the keyboard cover the field?
I created another test table to see if I had screwed up some settings but it too no longer has support for this.
The apple docs say that support for this should be provided post 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that my class was a subclass of UIViewController when it needed to be UITableViewController.